# How to transfer clicked table row data to input while being updated

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am currently having a table which is being updated every 2 seconds using jsAjax.

```
<script>

 function loadXMLDoc()
 {
 var xmlhttp;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
 else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
     document.getElementById("divid").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; //  div
     }
   }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","url",true); // php file
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
 window.setInterval(function(){
   loadXMLDoc();
 }, 1000);



 </script>
```

In html there is only a div. The script is having path to a php file which prints a table every 2 second by fetching data from db. I want user to be able to click on any row and transfer the row content to the input area. I tried the following:-

```
<script>

                var table = document.getElementById('table');

                for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
                {
                    table.rows[i].onclick = function()
                    {

                         //rIndex = this.rowIndex;
                         var texte1 = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                         var texte2 = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
                         var texte3 = this.cells[2].innerHTML;                         
                         document.getElementById("Someinput1").value = texte1;
                         document.getElementById("Someinput2").value = texte2;
                         document.getElementById("Someinput3").value = texte3;
                    };
                }

         </script>
```

but this does not seem to work when table is being updated every 2 second but it works when it is not. It would be appreciated to help me out on how to fetch the table row data while it is also being updated live.

Sample Table:-

```
                  <thead>
                    <tr id='id_buy_orders_header'>
                      <td>Amount</td>
                      <td>Price</td>
                      <td>Total</td>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody id='id_buy_orders_body'>";
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qlr1))
    {

      echo '<tr>
                    <td>'.$row['sum(amount)'].$coin.'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['price'].$bm.'</td>
          <td>'.$row['sum(total)'].$bm.'</td>
        </tr>';
    }
    echo "</tbody>
                </table>";
```

Comment: Have you considered using JQuery?

Comment: havent tried yet

Comment: It is easy, simple and productive. I recommend it.

Comment: Natasha could you share sample HTML table it outputs? It's 2020 learning using jQuery is pointless.

Comment: Updated thread.